# How to display an alert if none of the case statements match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a case statement below where it checks for a file type in a file input which works correctly:

```
function imageValidation(imageuploadform) {
    var val = $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'gif':
        case 'jpg': 
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'pjpeg':
        case 'png':
             return true;
        default:
            $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
            // error message here
            alert("To upload an image, please select an Image File");
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now what happens is that if it matches one of the case statements then it returns true and by default it returns an alert which I want to use if file input is blank.

But how can I display this alert:

```
alert("Image File Type is Incorrect. Must be either: \n (jpg, jpeg, pjpeg, gif)")
```

If the file input does not match with one of the file type cases above?

Comment: Huh? Is this serious? What do you think `default` is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an empty case and it should work! The default case will catch everything hence catching your non-desired extensions!

```
case 'png':
     return true;
case '':
     $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
     // error message here
     alert("To upload an image, please select an Image File");
     return false;
default:
    alert("To upload an image, please select a valild file extension.");
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your default case, check if the value is blank. If it's blank, do what you currently have otherwise it has a value but doesn't match what you're looking for.